# Не сохраняются поля в форме Django

Tags: python, django, forms

views.py

```
from .models import Visitor, Worker, Documentation


def visitor_edit(request, pk):
    visitor = get_object_or_404(Visitor, pk=pk)

    if request.method == "POST":
    #передаём экземпляр visitor в качестве instance форме и при сохранении…
        form = VisitorForm(request.POST, instance=visitor)
        pform = WorkerForm(request.POST)
        dform = DocumentationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and pform.is_valid() and dform.is_valid():
            visitor = form.save(commit=False)
            worker = pform.save(commit = False)
            documentation = dform.save(commit = False)
            #visitor.author = request.user
            #visitor.published_date = timezone.now()
            visitor.save()
            worker.save()
            documentation.save()
            return redirect('visitor_detail', pk=visitor.pk)
    else:
    # и когда мы открываем форму для редактирования:
        form = VisitorForm(instance=visitor)
        pform = WorkerForm()
        dform = DocumentationForm()
    return render(request, 'bl/visitor_edit.html', {'form': form, 'pform' : pform, 'dform' : dform})


def visitor_new(request):   
if request.method == "POST":
    form = VisitorForm(request.POST, prefix='form')
    pform = WorkerForm(request.POST, prefix='pform')
    dform = DocumentationForm(request.POST, prefix='dform')

    if form.is_valid() and pform.is_valid() and dform.is_valid():
        visitor = form.save(commit=False)
        worker = pform.save(commit = False)
        documentation = dform.save(commit = False)
        #visitor.author = request.user
        #visitor.published_date = timezone.now()
        visitor.save()
        worker.save()
        documentation.save()
        return redirect('visitor_detail', pk=visitor.pk)
else:

    form = VisitorForm(prefix='form')
    pform = WorkerForm(prefix='pform')
    dform = DocumentationForm(prefix='dform')

    return render(request, 'bl/visitor_edit.html', {'form': form, 'pform' : pform, 'dform' : dform})
```

visitor_edit.html

```
{% block content %}
    <h1>Новый посетитель</h1>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {{ pform.as_p }}
        {{ dform.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Сохранить</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import Visitor, Worker, Documentation

class VisitorForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Visitor
        fields = ('name_visitor', 'surname_visitor', 'phone', 'address', 'entry_time', 'time_out')



class WorkerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Worker
        fields = ('name_worker', 'surname_worker' , 'position_worker')


class DocumentationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Documentation
        fields = ('document_type', 'document_number')
```

При заполнении формы в итоге сохраняются только поля, которые относятся к модели Visitor и соответственно VisitorForm.
Подскажите, что изменить, чтобы сохранялись поля во всех формах?

Answer (score 1):

Вы не провели валидацию форм `WorkerForm` и `DocumentationForm`.

Вам нужно проверять каждую форму на `is_valid()`, а не только `VisitorForm`.

Так-же добавим [префикс](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.prefix) к каждой форме.

Код `view` будет выглядеть примерно следующим образом:

```
from .models import Visitor, Worker, Documentation

def visitor_new(request):   
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = VisitorForm(request.POST, prefix='form')
        pform = WorkerForm(request.POST, prefixt='pform')
        dform = DocumentationForm(request.POST, prefix='dform')

        if form.is_valid() and pform.is_valid() and dform.is_valid():
            visitor = form.save(commit=False)
            worker = pform.save(commit = False)
            documentation = dform.save(commit = False)
            #visitor.author = request.user
            #visitor.published_date = timezone.now()
            visitor.save()
            worker.save()
            documentation.save()
            return redirect('visitor_detail', pk=visitor.pk)
    else:

        form = VisitorForm(prefix='form')
        pform = WorkerForm(prefixt='pform')
        dform = DocumentationForm(prefix='dform')

    return render(request, 'bl/visitor_edit.html', {'form': form, 'pform' : pform, 'dform' : dform})
```

Comment: Не пропускает не заполненные поля, но в итоге после их заполнения они всё равно не отображаются. 
При нажатии на запись, чтобы отредактировать ее, эти поля оказываются пустыми, т.е. ощущение, что они заполнены не были. Хотя я заполняла..

Comment: "При нажатии на запись" - т.е. при submit'е заполненных данных в формах? и где вы смотрите, что данные не заполнены. посмотрите во вью, какие значения есть в request.POST при submit'e формы

Comment: Отредактировал ответ, проверьте так.

Comment: Я исправила в вопросе код. Т.е. при добавлении нового пользователя - у меня вызывается метод visitor_new
Когда пользователь уже добавлен и я хочу его отредактировать, у меня вызывается метод visitor_edit.
когда я нажимаю отредактировать запись, вижу, что поля от модели Visitor заполнены (они как раз нормально отображаются), остальные пустые

Comment: Нет, не получается

Comment: А админке тоже не отображается

Comment: Посмотрите что приходит в request.POST как я уже просил, что бы понять какие данные передаются и добавьте prefix. Давайте будем решать одну задачу за раз

Comment: Я, если честно, не понимаю, где я должна это посмотреть. Я исправила в коде выше prefix, показала там два метода для сравнения. new - создаю пользователя, edit - редактирую пользователя

Comment: во вью сделайте `print(request.POST)` или в шаблоне `{{ request.POST }}`